# Websphere App Server 7.0.0.43 - IBM Java 1.6, Apache Wink, Rest Client TLSv1.2

Tags: rest, ssl, websphere

Recently upgraded websphere app server to TLSv1.2. Prior, with TLSv1, was able to interface with REST client using combination of javax.ws.rs, org.glassfish.jersey and javax.net.ssl. Wasn't able to get working once app server upgraded TLS. IBM instructed to apply [Feature Pack Web 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.installation.webfep20nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tins_install_web20.html) and interface with REST client using [Apache Wink.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.web20fepmobilejaxrs.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_client_winkrestclient.html) Haven't been able to get this solution to work. Previously, Keystore and Truststore were set on SSLContext.

```
        private static  String getClient(String servicePath){
        try {
            javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = null;
            org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig clientConfig = new org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig();
            int readTimeOut = Integer.parseInt(commonProp.getProperty(READ_TIMEOUT));
            int connTimeout = Integer.parseInt(commonProp.getProperty(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT));
            clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connTimeout);
            clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, readTimeOut);
                org.glassfish.jersey.SslConfigurator sslConfig;
                String trustStoreName = commonProp.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_NAME);
                File file1 = new File("\\"+PROJECT_FILE_DIR+ "/ISB"+trustStoreName.trim());
                String keyStoreName = commonProp.getProperty(KEYSTORE_NAME);
                File file2 = new File("\\"+PROJECT_FILE_DIR+ "/ISB"+keyStoreName.trim());
                FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
                FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);

                String trustStorePassword = commonProp.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD);
                String keyStorePassword = commonProp.getProperty(KETSTORE_PASSWORD);
                sslConfig = org.glassfish.jersey.SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreBytes(ByteStreams.toByteArray(fis1))
                        .trustStorePassword(trustStorePassword).keyStoreBytes(ByteStreams.toByteArray(fis2))
                        .keyPassword(keyStorePassword);
                javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
                client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).withConfig(clientConfig).build();

            String url = commonProp.getProperty(ENDPOINT_URL)+servicePath;
            Response response =
                    client.target(url)
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get();
            String responseAsString = "";
            if(response != null){
                     responseAsString = response.readEntity(String.class);

            }
            return responseAsString;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.severe(e.getMessage() + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

With Installed Feature Pack and use of JSSEHELPER, retrieved SSL alias 
information from WAS. Seem to make client connection now, but still have 
authentication issue

> Blockquote
>   *response statusCode: 200
>   called close()
>   called closeInternal(true)
>   WebContainer : 0, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
>   An attempt to authenticate with a client certificate failed.  A valid client 
>   certificate is required to make this connection.* 
>   Blockquote

Believe issue may be that previously the KEYSTORE and TRUSTSTORE information 
was read from file. Whereas the JSSEHELPER is simply putting file name.

```
    com.ibm.ssl.clientAuthenticationSupported = false
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreClientAlias = isbgatewaytst
com.ibm.ssl.contextProvider = IBMJSSE2
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreProvider = IBMJCE
com.ibm.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreReadOnly = false
com.ibm.ssl.alias = ISBGatewaySSL
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreCreateCMSStash = false
com.ibm.ssl.securityLevel = CUSTOM
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreName = ISBGatewayTrust
com.ibm.ssl.configURLLoadedFrom = security.xml
com.ibm.ssl.trustStorePassword = ********
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreUseForAcceleration = false
com.ibm.ssl.trustManager = PKIX
com.ibm.ssl.validationEnabled = false
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreInitializeAtStartup = false
com.ibm.ssl.keyManager = IbmX509
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreFileBased = true
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreType = JKS
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreFileBased = true
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreCreateCMSStash = false
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreScope = (cell):ESB_DEV
com.ibm.ssl.trustStore = E:/IBM/content/resources/dev_projectfiles_dir/ISB/isb-truststore.jks
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreProvider = IBMJCE
com.ibm.ssl.enabledCipherSuites = SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
com.ibm.ssl.daysBeforeExpireWarning = 60
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreServerAlias = isbgatewaytst
com.ibm.ssl.clientAuthentication = false
com.ibm.ssl.keyStore = E:/IBM/content/resources/dev_projectfiles_dir/ISB/isb-keystore-tst.jks
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreUseForAcceleration = false
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreReadOnly = false
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreScope = (cell):ESB_DEV
com.ibm.ssl.tokenEnabled = false
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreName = ISBGatewayPrivatekey
com.ibm.ssl.keyStorePassword = ********
com.ibm.ssl.keyStoreInitializeAtStartup = false
com.ibm.ssl.trustStoreType = JKS
```

My issue is how to put the KEYSTORE and TRUSTSTORE information on the org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig or else where, similar to previously setting the javax.net.ssl.SSLContext? Did set the WAS SSL alias information on the ClientConfig properties, but believe that is just adding the Store's file location which isn't of use for the REST Client.

```
        public static String getPPLUResponseString(String servicePath) {
        String responseAsString = "";
        com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper jsseHelper = com.ibm.websphere.ssl.JSSEHelper.getInstance();
        try {
            Properties sslProps = null;
            String alias = "ISBGatewaySSL";
            sslProps = jsseHelper.getProperties(alias, getConnectionInfo(), null);

            org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig clientConfig = new org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig();
            clientConfig.readTimeout(Integer.parseInt(commonProp.getProperty(READ_TIMEOUT)));
            clientConfig.connectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(commonProp.getProperty(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)));
            clientConfig.setProperties(sslProps);

            Enumeration keys = clientConfig.getProperties().keys();
            while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
                String value = (String) clientConfig.getProperties().get(key);
                System.out.println(" clientConfig.getProperties(): " + key + ": " + value);
            }

            org.apache.wink.client.RestClient restClient = new org.apache.wink.client.RestClient(clientConfig);

            String url = commonProp.getProperty(ENDPOINT_URL) + servicePath;
            System.out.println(" url: " + url);

            org.apache.wink.client.Resource restResource = restClient.resource(url);

            System.out.println(" before client response");
            org.apache.wink.client.ClientResponse clientResponse = restResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();

            int statusCode = clientResponse.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println(" response statusCode: " + statusCode);

            String responseEntity = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println(" responseEntity start: " + responseEntity);
            System.out.println(" responseEntity end: ");
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                responseAsString = responseEntity;
            }
        } catch (com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException e) {
            System.out.println(" com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return responseAsString;
    }
```

Comment: Does your client cert use a reasonable signature algorithm? TLS1.2 would give the server an oppty to restrict that.

Comment: This was info provided by client. Shows TLSv1.2 and proper ciphers.         TLSv1.2:  server selection: enforce server preferences   3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384   3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256   3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA Tomcat Server Level: ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,T
LS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

Comment: Those just look like ciphers.  That doesn't really say anything about the signature algorithms used in the client certificates chain.

Comment: Same info was sent with TLSv1. How would signature algorithms come into play with TLSv1.2?